# my cookie-navbar combo isn't working, even though I don't get errors

Tags: python, django

I have this in my view for when someone registers for an acccount:

```
    response =  redirect ("/register/success")
    response.set_cookie('register', 'True')
    return response
```

This creates a cookie so I know they are registered.

Then, I have this in my navbar:

```
<ul>
  <li class="all"><a href="/">All videos</a></li>
  <li class="stam"><a href="/stam">Stam videos</a></li>
  <li class="music"><a href="/music">Music videos</a></li>
  <li class="news"><a href="/news">News videos</a></li>
  <li class="contact"><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
  {% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <li class="logout"><a href="/logout">Logout</a></li>
  {% elif request.COOKIE.register == 'True' and user.is_authenticated == 'False' %}
        <li class="login"><a href="/login">Login</a></li>
  {% else %}
    <li class="register"><a href="/register">Register</a></li>
  {% endif %}
</ul>
```

Basically, if the user is logged in shows 'logout' in the navbar (this works), if they are logged out it shows 'register', and if they are logged out and have the 'register' cookie it says 'login'. However, this last one doesn't work, and I don't know why, because I don't get any errors in relation to making a cookie when I make an account, but eveen after I make an account and logout it doesn't show 'login'.

Here is my full register view:

```
from django import forms
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login

CARRIER_CHOICES =(
    ('@txt.freedommobile.ca', 'Freedom Mobile'),
    ('@txt.luckymobile.ca', 'Lucky Mobile'),
    ('none', 'None'),
    )

class RegisterForm (forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField()
    password = forms.CharField()
    check_password = forms.CharField()
    email = forms.EmailField()
    phone = forms.IntegerField(required=False)
    carrier = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CARRIER_CHOICES, required=False)

def register (request):
    form_error = 'none'
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            check_password = form.cleaned_data['check_password']
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            phone = form.cleaned_data['phone']
            carrier = form.cleaned_data['carrier']
            phone = str(phone)
            if password == check_password:
                phone_email = phone + carrier
                user = User.objects.create_user(username, email, password)
                user.is_staff = False
                user.is_active = True
                user.is_superuser = False

                user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
                login(request, user)

                send_mail(
                    'TachlisGeredt.com Account',
                    'Congrats! You have succesfully created an account with TachlisGeredt.com!',
                    'contact@tachlisgeredt.com',
                    [email],
                    fail_silently=False,
                )
            response =  redirect ("/register/success")
            response.set_cookie('register', 'True')
            return response
    else:
        form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
    return render (request, 'register.html', {'form':form})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code like this:

```
{% elif request.COOKIE.register == 'True' and not user.is_authenticated %}
    <li class="login"><a href="/login">Login</a></li>
{% else %}
```

- Using `not user.is_authenticated` instead of `user.is_authenticated == 'False'`